# Elasticsearch configuration failed to load bundle

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using Gradle (Spring Boot 1.4.2, Thymeleaf, Elasticsearch 2.3.4) and I'm working locally.
I'm trying to implement Thymeleaf security using `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` module but I faced a problem.

I got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDashboardDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDashboardRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDashboardRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load bundle [file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/antlr4-runtime-4.5.1-1.jar, file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/asm-5.0.4.jar, file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/asm-commons-5.0.4.jar, file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/lang-expression-2.3.4.jar, file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/lucene-expressions-5.5.0.jar] due to jar hell
```

My `build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin: 1.4.2.RELEASE")
   }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
jar {
     baseName = 'Selva'
     version =  '0.1.0'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
dependencyManagement {
     imports {
         mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.4.2.RELEASE'
     }
}
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
     ext.mainClass = '*.*.config.Application'
 }
 configurations {
      provided
 }
 repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven {
         url "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2"
       }
      maven {
       url "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"
      }
     }
  dependencies {
     compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.193'
compile group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect', version: '2.1.1'
compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4', version: '3.0.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of JAR hell.

You have a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:1.4.0.RELEASE'` which will import `org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch`  which in turn imports `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch`.

Aside from this, you're importing `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.3.4` directly, which means that you'll end up with two elasticsearch JARs, hence the JAR hell.

If you're using the `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`, you shoulnd't need to have your own import for `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch`.

Remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: Were you able to test this?